# special outfile mysql with string inserted?

Tags: mysql, string, text, fastq

I have 3 columns in a mysql table like that

```
COL1       COL10      COL11
longblob1 longblob10  longblob11
```

I want to output everything with the following format :

```
 @COL1 COL10
 +
 COL11
```

(It's called a fastq file for lil' biochemist like me out there ..)

So I thought querying the output like that, but it doesn't go to next line it just prints out /n as a character ..  :

```
SELECT '@',COL1, COL10,'/n','+','/n',COL11 FROM MYTABLE
INTO OUTFILE '/MYPATH/MYFILE.TXT';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for string concatenation (additionaly, you are escaping wrong, it's `\n`, not `/n`):

```
SELECT CONCAT('@', COL1, COL10, '\n+\n', COL11) FROM MYTABLE
INTO OUTFILE '/MYPATH/MYFILE.TXT';
```

Learn more about **[`CONCAT()` here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)**.

Answer (score 0):

It should if you use the concat() function:

```
SELECT CONCAT('@',COL1, COL10,'\n','+','\n',COL11) FROM MYTABLE
INTO OUTFILE '/MYPATH/MYFILE.TXT';
```